# master node in multi-node kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to set up a multi node kafka cluster and have the following three config files. But how do I know which node is the master?

```
broker.id=1
port=9093
log.dir=/data/logs/kafka/kafka-logs-1
```

in config/server1.properties

```
broker.id=2
port=9093
log.dir=/data/logs/kafka/kafka-logs-2
```

in config/server2.properties

```
broker.id=3    
port=9093
log.dir=/data/logs/kafka/kafka-logs-3
```

in config/server3.properties

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kafka does not have a notion of "master" and "slave" nodes with regards to its brokers (unlike related technologies such as Apache Hadoop, Spark, or Storm).  "All brokers are created equal", so to speak.  So this is good news -- you don't need to configure anything special!  All you need to do is to start the three broker processes*, and they will transparently figure out how to cooperate.

And yes, there is a notion of [leaders and followers for topic partitions/replicas](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_leader_balancing), but all of this is automagically managed behind the scenes for you.  Also, leader/follower assignments are dynamic and may change at runtime.  For example, if broker `B1` is the current leader of partition `P8` and broker `B1` subsequently crashes, then one of the brokers that are the followers for partition `P8` will automatically be elected as the new leader for `P8` (say, broker `B3`).  Once broker `B1` is alive again, it will typically become a follower of the newly elected leader `B3` with regards to partition `P8`.

**I assume these processes will run on different machines, otherwise (i.e. in case all three broker processes run on a single machine) you must assign different `port` settings to each process.*

Comment: I also need to start three Zoo Keepers right? Is there master /slave nodes in ZK?

Comment: The minimum number of ZK instances you need is 1.  The number should be odd.  Production environments typically run 3 or 5 instances.  Like Kafka, there's no master/slave notion in ZooKeeper (as per your understanding above);  but, similar to Kafka, ZK has leaders and followers.  Specifically, there's always 1 leader ZK instance and the remaining ZK instances are followers. http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperOver.html